# Use content panes as blocks

Tags: panels

I am currently working with drupal 7 and I'm using page manager to edit different pages on the site.

I tried creating a mini panel and adding it to a region, but i do not know how to add content panes to it. Is it possible to use content panes as blocks and add then to regions ? the reason I wanna try doing this is i don't want to choose a layout from page manager and add content panes to it instead i wanna add then to the drupal regions.

Answer (score 1):

A mini panel acts like a block, except that it has subregions.  To add content, select the mini panel for editing and select the "content" editing display.  Next pick the gear in the upper right corner of the desired region in the mini panel and select 'add content'  The pop-up will give you the selection of available content that can be placed in the panel.

Once you have the mini panel configured, you place it in a theme region just as you would a block.  You select the mini panel from the admin/structure/blocks page for your theme.  It can be found in the list of disabled blocks at the bottom of the layout page form.