# Block within another block

Tags: 7, blocks

In drupal 7, I want to render block into another block, for example block-1 into block-2. 
I guess I should put some PHP code into block-2, but I don't know what the code could be?

Comment: Putting "some PHP code into block" is a [very bad idea](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args/2512#2512). Please elaborate on what you want to accomplish, as this doesn't make sense without more context.

Comment: Are looking to multiple, related pieces of content together like a mini-panel? (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28266)

Comment: like <?php print render(block_load($module, $delta)); ?>?

Comment: @Letharion, "newsletter" module created "newsletter" block which I want to put that into some reserved place in other block

Comment: @Ashlar, Thanks for your response, I don't know what mini panel is, but I'm trying to figure that out :)

Comment: @artfulrobot, How should I specify which block I want to render? I'm not familiar with drupal coding.   by the way, Mr Letharion said putting php code in very bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ashlars's comment.

A minipanel, provided by [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), is for anyone not used to Panels, essentially a block, that supports internal layouts. You can use a mini-panel to wrap several different blocks (and many other things, views, nodes, etc) into a single "block".

Unfortunately, I must admit that documentation is scarce on this topic. I will refer you to this other question: [looking for a good mini panels tutorial](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18868/looking-for-a-good-mini-panels-tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

Completely agree with Letharion's comment but if there is absolute need for such, this code snippet can help:

```
<?php
//D7
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

If you are unsure what are exact parameters for **'module_name'** and **'block_delta'** I'd recommend searching the database table **block** and locating your specific

- module_name under column **module**
- block_delta under column **delta**

second parameter block_view remains exactly like that.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

Comment: Good solution, however, it might not a [best practice](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices), especially if the client has write access to the block (which they probably would, because that's what a CMS is for). The client breaks ***any*** PHP code, and the entire site goes down.

Comment: Beyond that issue, this sometimes is the sharpest way to go. To invoke a block, you'd use this code, for example: `<?php $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', BLOCK_ID_PASTE_HERE);
`

Comment: It was good to point out that find out the 'module_name' and 'block_delta' by searching DB, useful trick!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for anyone who comes across this.

The [cfrblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/cfrblock) module, based on [renderkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/cfrblock), allows to combine blocks and elements in any way you want, also supports conditional logic.

I am not sure if this covers the specific requirement of the original question:
The original question wants to insert block-1 into block-2.
What I am proposing here allows to create a new block which combines two existing blocks.

Follow the instructions on the module page:

- Install cfrblock, renderkit, cfrpreset. This involves some composer packages, you will find instructions on renderkit module page.
- Go to admin/structure/cfrpreset, add a preset for "BlockInterface".
- Configure the block as you like.
- Go to admin/structure/block. The presets you just created will appear there as blocks.

Possibilities when configuring the block:

- Sequence of elements (blocks or other things). This is, I think, what you want here.
- Views display.
- Views exposed form.
- Existing block.
- Element wrapped into a special container.
- Combination of the above, with endless nesting.

If you are crafty and creative, you can create your own elements and then recombine them into a block.

I am using this on a website where I have more custom plugins than you currently find in renderkit. I should add some of those to the contrib module..

NOTE: This is essentially the same answer I gave here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288747/2974. It applies in both cases.