# Loading a views block inside another block

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

I'm pretty new to this, but I have been stumbling on a feature I would like to have. I'm using Drupal 7.

I've created a some blocks on my front page. In one of those blocks I have a some div's and text that goes inside of my block. That works just fine and looks great.

Problem is that I want to place some randomly generated testimonials inside this block and I can't figure out how to do so.

Now, I've already created another view block that lists my testimonials randomly, but I just need to know the correct php code. Note: I've also enabled the PHP filter module, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I can easily assign my random testimonial view to a block, but I want to combine some HTML along with the testimonial and I just dont know enough about php.

Example:

Some random text here...

**PHP to bring in my random block of testimonials from views**

Some random text here...

I've also heard that placing in PHP like this is not good practice. If anyone has a better way for me to do this I would appreciate it. Like I mentioned, placing this view in a empty block works fine. I just want to be together with some html.

Thanks!

-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by following snippet in your block,

```
  Some random text here...
  echo views_embed_view('view-name', $display_id = 'display-name');
  Some random text here...
```

eg:

```
 <?php echo views_embed_view('test', $display_id = 'block'); ?> //dont forgot to enable text format as PHP.
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed and it works perfectly. Thanks Anoop!!

Comment: I can't get this to work. I'm using the following code (the first variable being the name of the view and the second being that view's block display name)

Comment: I'm using the following code and its not working.
'home-page'totals' is the name of the block and 'ipe-resources' is the disp

<?php echo views_embed_view('home-page-totals', $display_id = 'ipe-resources'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Insert block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) (it's div version but it work perfectly)module to insert a block into another block.
See the Readme file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion abd. I'd love to do this without another module. Is what I want to do that strange? I went ahead and moved my html back into the template with my php string of " <?php print render($page['twocolumn']); ?>" and now its working fine. But I guess sometime down the road I will learn why its not good to put html content inside a template file.

Comment: don't worry #dan :D

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for anyone who comes across this.

The [cfrblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/cfrblock) module, based on [renderkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/cfrblock), allows to combine blocks and elements in any way you want, also supports conditional logic.

Follow the instructions on the module page:

- Install cfrblock, renderkit, cfrpreset. This involves some composer packages, you will find instructions on renderkit module page.
- Go to admin/structure/cfrpreset, add a preset for "BlockInterface".
- Configure the block as you like.
- Go to admin/structure/block. The presets you just created will appear there as blocks.

Possibilities when configuring the block:

- Sequence of elements (blocks or other things).
- Views display.
- Views exposed form.
- Existing block.
- Element wrapped into a special container.
- Combination of the above, with endless nesting.

If you are crafty and creative, you can create your own elements and then recombine them into a block.

I am using this on a website where I have more custom plugins than you currently find in renderkit. I should add some of those to the contrib module..