# Rules Link - Insert into System Node Content Template Variant

Tags: rules, navigation

I'm trying to incorporate a Rules Link into an edited Panels Node Template Variant (Structure -> Pages -> Variant). The Rules Link is a simple "Apply Now" but I'm a little confused as to what I should be inserting as a Content. Previously it was working fine (the Rules Link added to the Content Node Field set and when any said content type was viewed it was there).

This item when I look at the content types available (Activity through to Widgets), I select Form (and available content) or Node or Node Token Type), all I get on the saved Node Template when viewing is basic text 'Entity info.' in the said Block and no actual Rules Link (ie general 'blue' URL link).
My efforts to get it to show in the Node Variant is not a success and I've tried the Content types available for insert. I roughly understand what is happening and how things 'should' work and presumed what I did before would merely work in the edited Node, it seems quite self explanitory but not having much joy at this stage or maybe I'm merely missing a small point.

Could someone share with us the general process of getting a Rules Link to show in a Node Content Template Variant in order for the Rules Link to process to the next stage. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have found the answer to my original question above and solved it, though I'm not too sure if it would be the ideal (correct) approach, but it's ideal for now.
After reading this post [Use content panes as blocks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28266/use-content-panes-as-blocks) I approached my issue by using a Mini Panel to include the said Rules Link, it worked fine.
Put simply, I just created a Mini Panel, included the Rules Link as Content (see how in the above post), saved, then went back to my original Node Template Panel Variant, edited and included as a new Content in the Panel Editor, then saved that Panel. Voila!

You may have to fiddle with the Override Panel headings etc to get rid of any unwanted shown text: i.e Panel Name (I justed wanted the Link URL to trigger workflow and not the actual Mini Panel Title, so use the 'Override' Title option). It couldn't be that easy? well it is.

Sometimes I think we may over complicate Drupal, now in my opinon we shouldn't, we just need to see the wood from the trees. Clearly I'm learning Drupal, so will you.